# python LDA scikit learn throws ValueError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, valueerror

I have a pd.DataFrame with explanatory variables: X and another dataframe with target variables y.

```
type(X)
Out[1]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

X_num.shape
Out[2]: (1213, 3298)
```

and

```
type(y)

Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

y.shape
Out[4]: (1213, 8)
```

and I want to calculate a LDA using only one column of y:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
lda = LDA(n_components=2)
    for col in y:
        X_t = lda.fit(X.copy(), y[col].copy())
```

y has a column name

```
y[col].name
Out[5]: u'myvarname'
```

but I always get the error

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 0.001, 0.003 ...
```

I also tried

```
X_t = lda.fit(X.copy(), y[col].values.copy())
```

and got the same error.

According to the help fit requires as Y

```
Y : array-like of response, shape = [n_samples, n_targets]
Target vectors, where n_samples in the number of samples 
and n_targets is the number of response variables.
```

anyone an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear discriminant analysis is a *categorization* technique. According to your error, your `Y` values involve some sort of array of floating point values:

```
array([ 0.001, 0.003 ...
```

And `sklearn` doesn't know how to interpret this as category labels. Are you *sure* you should be using LDA and not some sort of regression?

Comment: great, converting to string did it. The y-values are categories but saved as floats therefore classification is the right tool.